# is there a proprietary java object pooling library?

Tags: java, object-pooling

I need to create a pool of socket connections (TCP). I'm planning to use commons pool but would like to know about any proprietary object pool libraries in the market.

Thank you
Bhargava

Comment: It quite common to dedicate a thread(s) per connection or a thread pool for a collection of Sockets.  I am not sure how useful a simple pool of Sockets is.

Answer (score 1):

Try checking this out. [PooliT](http://programming.huyduong.com/poolit/)

Comment: Thank you. Have seen this but this is also OSS. I'm looking for commercial library.

Answer (score 0):

Apache Commons provide a generic Object pooling library called [Pool](http://commons.apache.org/pool/)

It also has a database specific pooling library call [DBCP](http://commons.apache.org/dbcp/)

Comment: both are OSS. I would be needing a proprietary (read commercial) library.